# Changing Select dropdown to UL list

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to change the following a sorting dropdown element to show as a ul-li list,
the dropdown shows a list of categories, that when chosen filter the portfolio/gallery (ajax).
I tried simply changing th select to ul, and option to li, but that didn't work. I also tried jquery approach but still no luck, I do see the list, but the items are not clickable.

I will appreciate your help.
thanks

```
<select class="chosen-select filter_taxonomy" data-taxonomy="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>">
    <option value=""><?php gridfx_nice_dropdown_all($taxonomy); ?></option>             
    <?php foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>        
</select>
```

Comment: Why are you showing your PHP if this is a jquery question?

Comment: you need to show you javascript code. The solution will involve setting an onClick handler for the li elements that recognizes the click and fires the actions that you had set up for the dropdown